# Why all dates in a tuple are converted to datetime.today?

Tags: python, date, datetime, strftime

I read a list of dates from csv, and want to convert it to Python list/tuple in a readable format: yyyy-mm-dd.

STEP 1: Reading data from file

```
with open('pnl_data.csv', 'rb') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    my_lista = []
    for row in reader:
        my_lista.append(row[0])
```

STEP 2: I convert all elements to `datetime.datetime` format

```
my_lista = [xlrd.xldate_as_tuple(x, 0) for x in my_lista]
```

STEP 3: At last I want to format it to yyyy-mm-dd

```
my_lista = [strftime('%Y-%m-%d') for y in my_lista]
```

For some reason after executing step 3, all dates are changed to today's date.

PRINT OUTS:

AFTER EXECUTING STEP 2:

```
[(2014, 1, 3, 0, 0, 0), (2014, 1, 4, 0, 0, 0), (2014, 1, 5, 0, 0, 0)]
```

AFTER EXECUTING STEP 3:

```
['2014-08-28', '2014-08-28'. '2014-08-28']
```

Why all dates changed to current date?

Comment: You are just calling `strftime` without any mention of `y`, so it defaults to the current time - try `my_lista = [y.strftime('%Y-%m-%d') for y in my_lista]`

Comment: `Attribute Error: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'strftime'`

Comment: Oh, then `datetime(*y).strftime(...)`. I thought `y` was a `datetime` object at that point, for some unknown reason; sorry.

Comment: String formatting would work - ```['{}-{:02}-{:02}'.format(*x) for x in my_lista]```

Comment: hi jon, would you mind to write your comment as an official answer?